# What is the correct definition of correlation length?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

What is the definition of correlation length for discrete stochastic process $\{ X_i \}$?

We define variance $\text{var}(X) := E[(X - E[X])^2]$, standard deviation $\text{std}(X) := \sqrt{\text{var}(X)}$, covariance $\text{cov}(X, Y) := E[(X - E[X])(Y - E[Y])]$, correlation $\text{cor}(X, Y) := \frac{\text{cov}(X, Y)}{\text{std}(X)\text{std}(Y)}$.
We assume that $\{ X_i \}$ is stationary process.
I found there are two definitions of correlation length $\xi$ in physics,

1. $\langle X_i X_{i+n} \rangle = E[X_{i}X_{i+n}] \propto \exp{\left(-\frac{n}{\xi}\right)}$
2. $\langle (X_i - \langle X_i \rangle)(X_{i+n} - \langle X_{i+n} \rangle) \rangle = \text{cov}(X_i, X_{i+n}) \propto \text{cor}(X_i, X_{i+n}) \propto \exp{\left(-\frac{n}{\xi}\right)}$

Here, $E[X] := E[X_i]$ and $\text{cov}(X_i, X_{i+n}) = E[X_iX_{i+n}] - (E[X])^2$, so if $E[X] = 0$ then $E[X_i X_{i+n}] = \text{cov}(X_i, X_{i+n})$ and the two definitions are same.

To my understanding, for example, if I know that $\text{cor}(X_i, X_{i+n}) = p^n, p \in [0, 1]$, then the correlation length is defined according to def. 2,

$$
p^n = \alpha \text{exp}\left( - \frac{n}{\xi} \right), \alpha \in \mathbb{R} \\
n \log p = \log \alpha - \frac{n}{\xi} \\
\xi = \frac{1}{ - \log p + \frac{\log \alpha}{n}}
$$

Is it right?

And is the definition 1 always thought as $E[X] = 0$?

Comment: I'm voting to move this question to Mathematics SE because it is a math problem, even if it could have applications in physics.

Comment: @AaronStevens : I disagree : the correlation length is a physical concept and is not used in mathematics (outside mathematical physics).

Comment: BTW, the answers to the 2 questions are yes and yes.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Note that questions of the form "Is this right?" tend to be poor fits for this site because the answer, yes or no, is too short to be a valid answer. Please consider editing the question to be more open-ended and allow for longer answers.

Comment: Additionally, [stats.se] might also be an appropriate site.

Comment: I think this question is appropriate for physics.SE with the same reason for @YvanVelenik mentioned, but this is migrated to math.SE.